# Running Unix shell script to split, rename & append record count header to multiple files

Tags: shell, file, csv, unix

I have a large file I need to split into 80000 records which I can do by

```
split -l 80000 filename.out new_file
```

This splits all the files as `new_fileaa`, `new_fileab`, `new_fileac` etc... After running that I need a header in each file `h(recordcount)`. So all the files will have a header of `h80000` except for the last file.

I think I need to look for the min `wc -l` of the files and create a custom header for that file. Then all of files with `wc -l` = to 80000 I can just concat a generic `h80000` header file to. Please assist with this script.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
count=80000 # How many records per file it is that we want.

split -l "$count" filename.out new_file
for file in new_file*; do
    mv "$file" temp
    echo "h$count" > "$file"
    cat temp >> "$file"
done
rm temp
# $file is now the filename of the last file.
last_count="$(expr "$(wc -l "$file" | cut -d' ' -f 1)" - 1)"
# Replace, e.g., h80000 in the last file with the actual number of records
# it contains.
sed -i "s/h$count/h$last_count/" "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
split -l 80000 filename.out new_file



for file in $(ls /path/to/directory/new_file*);

do
        line_count=$(wc -l $file | awk ‘{print $1}’);
        perl -pi -e "print \"h$line_count\n\" if $.==1" $file;
done
```

This created the header for all files including the record count that was not 80,000. Thank you for your response.